# Dynamically configure FPGA from the ARM core?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, zynq

I'm bootstrapping a new stand-alone, network-attached project based on an FPGA. The target chip is from the Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+ series.

The architecture I'm thinking of is:

- All the network stack and latency-critical logic is implemented in
  hardware, and attached to a 100GE interface.
- The ARM cores would
  run Linux, handle all management systems (statistics and management
  agent, cluster maintenance server, ...), and be attached to a 1GE interface.
- The two would be connected via a PCI-Express bus using [Riffa](http://riffa.ucsd.edu/)
  (for example).

One question I'm asking myself is whether it is possible to program the FPGA right from the linux distribution running on the ARM cores, using command-line tools. Or does it have to be done right from an external device?

Doing so would allow seamless user logic updates without adding yet another chip in the box dedicated to performing remote upgrades.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the Xilinx documentation have to say about this?

Comment: I have not managed to find any information about this in the docs, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a path but you should read the docs to be sure.  From the Xilinx docs

> The PL can be configured and reconfigured by PS software in secure or non-secure mode. The PCAP path is the most commonly deployed method as it does not require that the PL be pre-programmed with a bitstream. The PL can also be configured by the TAP controller on the JTAG chain in non-secure mode. Multiplexing of the datapath is done in the PL configuration module using the devc.CTRL [PCAP_MODE] and [PCAP_PR] bits. Also refer to section 6.5 Reference Section.

Comment: Looks like I did not use the right keywords for my search. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a linux made with petalinux up to 2017.4 you might have a look at this:

https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841833/Programming+the+Programmable+Logic

In a linux console try

Program

```
cat MyBitstream.bit > /dev/xdevcfg
```

Check if succesful (==1)

```
cat /sys/class/xdevcfg/xdevcfg/device/prog_done
```